# Creating Datastrip (2D) barcode with C#

Tags: c#, dll, 2d, barcode

Can anyone point me to a Barcode generating C# library that can help me generate `Datastrip 2D Barcodes` . I have already found tons of libraries but none of them support Datastrip 2D barcodes.

Comment: Here you go [QR/barcode generator](http://www.onbarcode.com/csharp/qr-code-generator.html#generator)

Comment: Google is usually a good friend in these cases ;-)

Comment: I can't see Datastrip in the link provided above. It has DataMatrix 2D which I've used in the past and other 2D ones, but does not mention Datastrip 2D (unless it also goes by another name).

Datastrip doesn't seem to be available in most of the libraries. I think you would have to contact the makes of it directly. There are contact details at the bottom of this link.
http://www.secureidnews.com/news-item/datastrips-advanced-2d-bar-code-system-helps-reduce-id-fraud/

Comment: I tried to contact them but their website and mailing server is down. i cant find them or a way to create Datastrip 2D anywhere

Answer (score 0):

no 3rd party dll.  you can create barcode from C# code itself.. not so hard and tricky.. check the below link..

http://mytactics.blogspot.in/2014/01/generate-barcode-in-c-string-to-image.html

it gives you an image you can display save whatever you want.

Comment: This uses 3of9 barcode, not Datastrip 2D Barcode. They are very different things. I've used 3of9 extensively in my work and it's the simplest and easiest to use as no algorithm is needed to convert the string before applying it. There are many others and the question is about a 2D one.

Comment: i thought he mean by datastrip 2d is bar code so i suggested this example.

Comment: guys i can only use Datastip 2D encoding. so please stay on that.